# Create detail page for catalog with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i try to learn how to create a catalog website with angular.
I create a catalog that contain many products. when i click one of the product, i intend to go to the detail page of that selected product.

on my app.js

```
angular
.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'app.directives.productCard'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home',{
            url: '/',
            templateUrl:'templates/pages/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('about',{
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl:'templates/pages/about.html'
        })
        .state('product',{
            url: '/product',
            templateUrl:'templates/pages/product.html',
            controller: 'productCtrl'
        })
        .state('productDetails',{
            url: '/product/:id',
            templateUrl:'templates/pages/productDetails.html',
            controller: 'productDetailsCtrl'
        })
        .state('contact',{
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl:'templates/pages/contact.html'
        })
}])
```

on my services product

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Product', ['$http', function($http){
        return{
            get: function(){
                return $http.get('/api/products.json').then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        };
    }])
```

on my directive.js

```
angular
    .module('app.directives.productCard',[])
    .directive('productCard', function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            scope:{
                item:'='
            },
            templateUrl: "templates/directive/product.html",
            controller:function($scope){
                console.log($scope.item);
            }
        };
    });
```

on product controller

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('productCtrl',['$scope', 'Product', function($scope,Product){
        $scope.title="List Product";
        Product.get().then(function(data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });
        $scope.products=Product.get();
    }]);
```

on my product.html

```
<section class="product-outer-container">
    <section class="product-inner-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-repeat="item in products">
                    <div data-product-card item="item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

on my directive html page

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top"  ng-src="{{item.image}}" alt="{{item.name}}">
      <div class="card-block">
        <strong class="card-title">{{item.name}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Detail</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

json only contain file like this

```
[
      {
         "name":"one",    "image":"http://images.thenorthface.com/is/image/TheNorthFace/236x204_CLR/mens-better-than-naked-jacket-AVMH_LC9_hero.png",    
         "description":"Shop Now",
         "price":132,
         "qty":2
      },
      {
         "name":"two",         "image":"http://images.thenorthface.com/is/image/TheNorthFace/236x204_CLR/womens-better-than-naked-jacket-AVKL_NN4_hero.png",
         "description":"lorem ipsum dolor",
         "price":126,
         "qty":22
      }
]
```

i kinda stuck when i want to make the the button detail work.
i know i missed a lot of stuff. 
on my product page i just want to show image and name only.
but when on detail page i intend to show all the data of that product.

Comment: You will need a new state that goes to /product/:id. That takes you to a new view, the controller fetches the product by its ID and you display it.

Comment: I don't see any productCtrl implemented in your code I suggest you create a jsfiddle. It's easier to help you that way

Comment: @juanin updated my description

Comment: @vandi check my answer below with the **LIVE DEMO**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you some thing like this without use of directives and have the id of the product in the parameter. Look the code below

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World'; 
});
app.config(function($stateProvider){

  $stateProvider
  .state('home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl:'listing.html',
        controller: 'productlistCtrl',
        param :{
          id: null


        }

    })
   .state('product',{
        url: '/product/:id',
        templateUrl:'product.html',
        controller: 'productCtrl',
        param :{
          id: null


        }

    })

});
app.controller('productlistCtrl', function($http,$scope) {
  $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
    $scope.Data=response;
  console.log(response);

  })
  .error(function(){

    //error handling
  });
});
  app.controller('productCtrl', function($http,$stateParams,$scope) {
  console.log("REACHED HERE");
  $scope.productID= $stateParams.id;
  console.log($scope.productID);
});
```

You should modify the json to have  id in it as a property

```
 [
      {
        "id"  :1,
         "name":"one",    "image":"http://images.thenorthface.com/is/image/TheNorthFace/236x204_CLR/mens-better-than-naked-jacket-AVMH_LC9_hero.png",    
         "description":"Shop Now",
         "price":132,
         "qty":2
      },
      {
        "id"  :2,
         "name":"two",         "image":"http://images.thenorthface.com/is/image/TheNorthFace/236x204_CLR/womens-better-than-naked-jacket-AVKL_NN4_hero.png",
         "description":"lorem ipsum dolor",
         "price":126,
         "qty":22
      }
]
```

You can navigate to the details page using this

```
 <a href="#/product/{{item.id}}" class="card-link">Detail</a>
```

You can get the details of the product which is clicked in the controller

```
app.controller('productCtrl', function($http,$stateParams,$scope) {
      console.log("REACHED HERE");
      $scope.productID= $stateParams.id;
      console.log($scope.productID);
    });
```

Here is the live plunker for the [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xxK8KKoQzg1oM1H17fxy?p=preview)

Comment: You should not be using http directly in the controller tho.  You should create a service to place your business logic. Best practice.

Comment: also are you using ui-router?  $stateParams is not part of ngrouter.

Comment: @btinoco. The question is not about best practise or standards or recommended usage! for example point of view I have posted this. how ever your answer can be combined using my solution to come up with a standard one. are u much worried regarding the best practice?

Comment: Mmmmm part of answering a question is to provide a "good way" of doing things besides just providing code.   Remember, some of the people asking questions are new to the technology and don't know that you are just giving an example but would take your code and copy it into their solution.  I am worry that we are providing answers that are sloppy and do not enforce best practices.  Anyone can answer questions not everyone provides good answers. We are coders... just my two cents.

Comment: thank you for both of answers. yeah i try to learn angular and try to understand it with beginner knowledge. mmm one question sir, why you didnt use directive? just curious

Comment: Use directives when there is a need of using it. I felt this situation does not need a directive.

Comment: @btinoco. providing good answers is definitely appreciable. Kindly check out your answer, the getProductDetails() method returns a **promise** is that a good solution?

Comment: @Aravind its a async function you have to return a promise. Did i miss something?

Comment: returning promise directly is not a best practice.

Comment: @Aravind what do you mean? Give me an example. http is an async function you have to return a promise.   Please show me the way to do it correctly according to best practices and I will correct it.

Comment: Check it now...I am using $q now... is that what you were talking about?

Comment: i think my example is bad for you guys let me make a new thread and ill give you guys notif, its a pleasure if you guys want to help

Comment: no your example is ok, you are loading a json file with objects and want to show details for each individual object in a view.   nothing hard.

Comment: @vandi I can't get you. Did this solve ur requirement?

Comment: yeah i combine both of you guys answer. i try to not change the app,js too much cause i still easy to confused. and i use the filter for id  and @state params like you guys told me. and then i got on console undefined. turn out i didnt specify the url, after i change to  '{id:int}' and now i got all the attribute of each product. heres the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023308/status-undefined-when-try-to-fetch-data-on-json-and-place-it-on-single-page-of-e/41023385#41023385 i try to reach you guys out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new state for product details. In your new route you can add a ":id" or ":name" or any unique field in your catalog items which will be use to fetch for the product.

```
$stateProvider
   .state('product',{
    url: '/product/:id',
    templateUrl:'templates/pages/productDetails.html',
    controller: 'productDetailsCtrl'
})
```

After creating the new route for product detail, create a function in your service to fetch for the specific product:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Product', ['$http','$q', '$filter', function($http, $q, $filter){
        return{
            getProductDetails: function(id){

                var defer = $q.defer;

               $http.get('/api/products.json').then(function(response){

                    var foundItem = $filter('filter')(response.data, {id:id}, true);

                    defer.resolve(foundItem[0]);

                },function(error){

                    defer.reject(error);

                });

                return defer.promise;
            }
        };
    }])
```

Once you get the product details, you can lay them out on your view however you want. You can access the id from your controller like this if using ui-router:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('productDetailsCtrl',['$scope', 'Product', function($scope, $stateParams, Product){

        var productId = $stateParams.id;

        Product.getProductDetails(productId).then(function(data) {
            $scope.productsDetails = data;
        });

}]);
```

Comment: sir let me ask something, doest that id is the refference of id from json or not? if yes, then if the product didnt have `"id":"1"`(for example), how to get that id?

Comment: the id will be whatever your object id is for example:

{
    id:"one"
}

then your id will be /product/one or 

{
    id: 1
}

then your id will be /product/1

It does not have to be id it can be any unique property for each item

Comment: it does not have be id it can be name or any other unique property..

{
   name:"one"
}

then your route url can look like this:  url: '/product/:name' and you will look for it like this:  url: /product/one

Comment: hello sir i follow your instruction and i add an id for each product on json. but i got error like this `angular.js:12185 GET /api/products.json1 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @vandi since you are not using a real service, you will need to load the json file,  use the $routeParams.id to search for the object with that id and then show that object in the productDetails. Let me create a plunker.

Comment: check the answer again... I added the $filter filter to the service in my answer. The filter will filter the list for the item with the id you are passing and will return it.