# status undefined when try to fetch data on json and place it on single page of each data

Tags: angularjs, json

heres my code, i try to show my selected product form my product page by id.
for example when i click a product it go to right url like `/#/product/2` and it show all the attribute of product id:2. please take a look this code

app.js

```
angular
 .module('app', [
  'ui.router',
  'app.directives.productCard'
 ])
 .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/pages/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
   })
   .state('product', {
    url: '/product',
    templateUrl: 'templates/pages/product.html',
    controller: 'productCtrl'
   })
   .state('productDetails', {
    url: '/product/:id',
    templateUrl: 'templates/pages/productDetails.html',
    controller: 'productDetailsCtrl'
   })
 }])
```

my services

```
angular
     .module('app')
     .factory('Product', ['$http', function($http) {
      return {
       get: function() {
        return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json').then(function(response) {
         return response.data;
        });
       }
      };
     }])
```

productCtrl

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('productCtrl',['$scope', 'Product', function($scope,Product) {
        $scope.title="List Product";
        Product.get().then(function(data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });
        $scope.products=Product.get();
    }]);
```

productdetailsCtrl

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('productDetailsCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams', 'Product', function($scope,$stateParams,Product){
        $scope.id=$stateParams.id;
        Product.get().then(function(data) {
            var singleProduct = data.filter(function(entry){
                return entry.id === $scope.id;
            })[0];
            console.log(singleProduct);
            console.log($stateParams);
        });
}]);
```

product.html

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top"  ng-src="{{item.image}}" alt="{{item.name}}">
      <div class="card-block">
        <strong class="card-title">{{item.name}}</strong>

      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
        <a href="#/product/{{item.id}}" class="card-link">Buy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

product detail.html

```
<p>{{id}}</p>   
<p>{{name}}</p>
<p>{{image}}</p>
```

after all this code,when i try to check via console. i get `Object {id: "2"}`, but when i try to show all the attribute from product 2 i get on console undefined. why i got `undifined`. yeah i didnt use and local server. but if its the problem. does all the code is right to print all the attribut of product 2

here the link of the json https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vicariosinaga/learn/master/products.json

Comment: @Aravind heres new code isr

Comment: @btinoco hello sir i put some code from your prev answer., how about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change product details state `url` to make `id` parameter as a `int` which will allow you to pass `return entry.id === $scope.id;`(strict equality check).Here you have `id` value as string which makes `singleProduct` as `undefined`.

```
.state('productDetails', {
  url: '/product/{id:int}',
  templateUrl: 'templates/pages/productDetails.html',
  controller: 'productDetailsCtrl'
})
```

otherwise you have to change your strict check to `return entry.id == $scope.id;`

Comment: thank you, i got all the attribute on console right now. would you like to tell me which better, change the url on state like that or change the productdetails controller code?

Comment: @vandi changing `URL` of state would make more sense per me, as `id` will always be an `integer`

Comment: oh i see, so the problem because id is int on my problem, so my controller didnt work sir?

Comment: i mean because the url of state didnt get spesific to int so it cant be `return entry.id == $scope.id;`

Comment: @PankajParkar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998540/create-detail-page-for-catalog-with-angularjs/ this was the previous post regarding this!! I dont know what he actually wants. :(

Comment: @Aravind yeah after i try the suggest it show undefined. im sorry T_T